# Avoid react native initial page having some space on top

Tags: react-native

```
    const RootStack = MultiNavigator({
    Splash: {
        screen: Splash
    },
    Registration: {
        screen: Registration
    },
    WelcomeScreen: {
        screen: WelcomeScreen
    },
    HomeScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen
    }
 }, {
    initialRouteName: "HomeScreen",
 },
 );
```

what ever i rendered as initial page , some space is coming at top side. I have to avoid it. I used header: null/none/false. But no result.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your `App.js` code.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue, by using headerMode: none.

```
const RootStack = MultiNavigator({
Splash: {
    screen: Splash
},
Registration: {
    screen: Registration
}
}, {
    initialRouteName: "Registration",
    headerMode: "none"
});
```